# jquery chosen select trigger not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using jquery chosen select plugin to display and select multiple options dynamically. I can select multiple options on the UI both on chrome and ie11 but when it comes to dynamically retrieving the already selected options, chrome works just fine but ie11 fails. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <div class="editor-label" style="width:150px;">
                        @Html.Label("User to Impersonate")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownList("usersImpersonationId", new SelectList(Model, "WindmillUserId", "Username"), new { @class = "chosen", multiple = "multiple" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".chosen").chosen({
                disable_search_threshold: 10,
                no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                width: "50%"
            });

..................

function GetImpersonatedUsers() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Impersonate/GetAllUsersImpersonated?UserId=" + $('#impersonationId').find('option:selected').val(),
                    type: "GET"
                })
                .done(function (jsonResult) {
                    console.log('jsonResult => %o', jsonResult);
                    $("#usersImpersonationId > option").each(function () {
                        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                    });
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResult.length; i++) {
                        $('#usersImpersonationId option[value="' + jsonResult[i] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
                    }
                    $('#usersImpersonationId').trigger("liszt:updated");
                    //$('#usersImpersonationId').trigger('chosen:updated');

                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                });
            };
```

when I load the options dynamically and trigger the control update, it works in chrome and the html is as follows (I can see the li options with class = search-choice:
[image]

But in case of ie11, the li options are not added even after triggering the update:
[image]

Is there any thing I am missing or ie11 is behaving as it should be?

Answer (score -2):

what does the console log for IE11 say? Is it throwing any errors or warnings?

Comment: you should add this as a comment on the question not an answer

Comment: there is no exception raised.